# Can I subfolder within a folder on the same page?

Tags: file

In explorer you can expand the view so you can see subfolders within a folder.  Can you do this on a sharepoint page?

Ex.

```
TopFolder1
   SubfolderA under TopFolder1
   SubfolderB under TopFolder1

TopFolder2
   SubfolderC under TopFolder2
FileZ
```

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as you must click on a folder to display its subfolders.

But I think that you can find thirs party plugins that do this trick for you.